# Django FormSet and PEP8 naming conventions

Tags: django, python-3.x, pep8, formset

I am wondering how I should name my formset definitions. Say I have a form called UserForm, then I would define a complementing form set like:

UserFormSet = modelform_factory(User, UserForm, extra=0)

Everyone post here regarding formsets seem to name theirs like the above.

But PyCharm tells me thats bad because UserFormSet is not a class definition.

Whats the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From django webpage [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/), the way you are assigning your Formsets is the correct way. The problem occurs because PyCharm is looking at the Formset assignment as a typical variable even though it is class. The return value from modelform_factory is as follows.

```
return type(form.__name__ + 'FormSet', (formset,), attrs)
# where
type(name, bases, dict)
```

As you can see it returns a class using bases of formset. So this error is ignorable or if possible you could try to override it. I am not familiar with PyCharm but this almost seems to be something they should add an exception for.